# How to correctly setup PyDev in NVIDIA Nsight Eclipse version?

Tags: pydev, nsight

In `Ubuntu 16.04(64 bit)`, I've installed the `cuda 7.5` and it has an internal NVIDIA Nsight Eclipse. Now I want to install the `PyDev` plugin into it. But it seems not working. The `PyDev` is not shown in the IDE.

So I searched in Google, it returns one solution in [here](http://vitrivs.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-install-pydev-on-nsight-eclipse.html), it can be worked. But in that way I have to using the `sudo` command.

Is there any more convenient way to successfully install the PyDev into Nsight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found one solution.

1. Download `PyDev-2.8.2.zip` and decompress it into the corresponding directories of `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/libnsight/`.
2. `sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/cuda-7.5 -R`

Then, when you rerun the `nsight`, the `PyDev` will be loaded and it works OK.

Comment: Didn't work anymore for me with Ubuntu 18.04, PyDev 7.1.0, Nsight 10.0. Choosing PyDev in the preferences leads to an error: `Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.python.pydev (340).`

Comment: @smcs, not sure how it works for the newer version. Maybe you should select the compatible PyDev version with the Nsight version.